# How can you maintain model state in ASP.NET Core between repeatedly displaying the Model in a View and sending the model back to the Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET Core and I've been learning the ropes over the past few weeks. I have a general question about how you can maintain the state of your model between adjusting it in a view, sending it to the back-end, the back-end manipulating it and sending it back to the view.

Basically, one of my model's has a list of strings. The user can adjust a value in a textbox, POST the view, and when I check in the VS debugger, the model coming back to the controller contains the text they input. That text is added to the list in my model on the back-end and the model is sent back to the view, i.e. View(myModel). All is hunky-dory, my UI displays an html unordered list with the now single element in my model list. However, if I add another value to my textbox input, POST the model again, my list now only contains the newly added text. It's like the model is created anew using only the values on the UI at the time it is POSTED, what gives? How am I able to ensure the list is persistent between repeatedly sending the model back-and-forth between the UI and the back-end?

Here is the code for the model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10,ErrorMessage ="Input string is too long.")]
    public string MyInput { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    public IFormFile DescriptionFile { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    public IFormFile MeasurementFile { get; set; }

    public List<string> MeasurementFilenames { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<string> DescriptionFilenames { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    [BindProperty]
    public string DescriptionDirectory { get; set; } 
    public string DescriptionExportFile { get; set; } 
    [BindProperty]
    public string MeasurementDirectory { get; set; } 
    public string MeasurementExportFile { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [BindProperty]
    public bool Session { get; set; } = false;

    public TestModel()
    {
    }

    public async Task OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (Session == false)
        {
            var token = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

            var directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"uploads\" + token + @"\");
            DescriptionDirectory = directory.CreateSubdirectory("Descriptions").FullName + @"\";
            DescriptionExportFile = directory.CreateSubdirectory(@"Descriptions\Exports\").FullName + DescriptionFile.FileName;
            MeasurementDirectory = directory.CreateSubdirectory("Measurements").FullName + @"\";
            MeasurementExportFile = directory.CreateSubdirectory(@"Measurements\Exports\").FullName + MeasurementFile.FileName;
            Session = true;
        }
        else if (Session == true)
        {
            DescriptionExportFile = DescriptionDirectory + @"Exports\" + DescriptionFile.FileName;
            MeasurementExportFile = MeasurementDirectory + @"Exports\" + MeasurementFile.FileName;
        }

        if (!MeasurementFilenames.Contains(MeasurementFile.FileName))
        {
            MeasurementFilenames.Add(MeasurementFile.FileName);
        }

        if (!DescriptionFilenames.Contains(DescriptionFile.FileName))
        {
            DescriptionFilenames.Add(DescriptionFile.FileName);
        }

        var file = Path.Combine(DescriptionDirectory, DescriptionFile.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await DescriptionFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ConfigureAwait(true);
        }

        file = Path.Combine(MeasurementDirectory, MeasurementFile.FileName);

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await MeasurementFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ConfigureAwait(true);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the view:

```
@* I need to add the namespace of C# models I'm creating *@
@using FirstASPNETCOREProject.ViewModels
@* I need to identify the model which 'fits' this page, that is the properties of the model can be bound to entities on the view page, using "asp-for" *@
@model TestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Page for File Uploads";
}
@section Scripts{
}
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" style="color:white"> </div>
<div class="col-4">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <label class="font-weight-bold h6">Enter a Description File Name</label>
                <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="font-weight-bold h6">Select a Description File</label>
                <input asp-for="DescriptionFile" type="file" class="form-control-file" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DescriptionFile"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <label class="font-weight-bold h6">Enter a Measurement File Name</label>
                <input asp-for="MyInput" type="text" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="MyInput"></span>
            </div>
            `  <div>
                <label class="font-weight-bold h6">Select a Measurement File</label>
                <input asp-for="MeasurementFile" type="file" class="form-control-file">
                <span asp-validation-for="MeasurementFile"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input asp-for="Session" type="checkbox" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit files" class="btn" />
    </form>
</div>
<br>


<div>
    <label >Active Description Files:</label>
    <ul>
        @if (Model != null && Model.DescriptionFilenames.Count > 0)
        {
            @foreach (var item in Model.DescriptionFilenames)
            {
                <li>@item</li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>
<br>

<div>
    <label >Active Measurement Files:</label>     
    <ul>
        @if (Model != null && Model.MeasurementFilenames.Count > 0)
        {
            @foreach (var item in Model.MeasurementFilenames)
            {
             <li>@item</li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>
<br>

<br>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Description File", "DownloadFile", "App", new { file = Model.DescriptionExportFile }) <span class="badge">@Model.DescriptionFilenames.Count.ToString()</span>
    <br>
    @Html.ActionLink("Measurement File", "DownloadFile", "App", new { file = Model.MeasurementExportFile })<span class="badge">@Model.MeasurementFilenames.Count.ToString()</span>
    <br>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: add your code to your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you want to keep, must be in the posted data & have `[BindProperty]`. `MeasurementFilenames` & `DescriptionFilenames` are not in the form, so their content will be lost.

```cs
    [BindProperty]
    public List<string> DescriptionFilenames { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

```
    @for(int i=0; i< Model.DescriptionFilenames.Count; i++)
    {
        <li><input type="hidden" asp-for="DescriptionFilenames[i]" />@Model.DescriptionFilenames[i]</li>
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The code you suggested works for me, however would you recommend this as a best practice? I don't need data necessarily sent back to the view, I just need data (in this case, a file directory) to remain constant through multiple submissions of the view. It seems that I should be using some type of object on the backend to store the data while the user interacts and submits the view.